# Remove all files except some with constant name and some containing a special in unix

Tags: unix, grep, ls, rm

I want to remove all files in a directory except some in UNIX. Part I desired files have a known name and for the other part, I'm using ls|grep command. But the ls | grep is working when there is only one occurrence and not when there is more than one. it is the same with find|grep. here are my commands:

```
rm -v !("R1.r"|"R2.r"|"r2.par"|$(ls|grep nario)|"sh.sh")

rm -v !("R1.r"|"R2.r"|"r2.par"|$(find|grep nario)|"sh.sh")
```

Is there any problem with my commands???

Comment: Your `ls | grep` is doing the same as `*nario*` as a glob; is that what you intended?  You mention 'containing' — I wonder if you mean `ls | xargs grep -l nario /dev/null` (where the mention of `/dev/null` prevents problems if there's only one file in one of the command lines run by `xargs`).  Note that it is generally best to avoid filtering the output from `ls`.\

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use BASH specific `extglob` syntax. `ls|grep` won't work in the middle of the glob, because each pattern needs to be separated by a `|`, which won't happen with `ls|grep`. The easier way to do what you want is to use the shell globbing to find the files under the directory you're looking for instead. Make sure you do the following:

1. Are using BASH
2. Have `extglob` enabled: `shopt -s extglob`
3. Have `globstar` enabled: `shopt -s globstar`
4. Use file globbing rather than `ls | grep`

Then try again:

```
rm -v !("R1.r"|"R2.r"|"r2.par"|**/*nario*|"sh.sh")
```

Note: `globstar` requires BASH version 4 or higher.